# RedirectMatch and Query String

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, mod-rewrite, querystring, mod-alias

Compare these two `RedirectMatch`'s. The first doesn't work:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/redirect\.php[?]page=(.+)$ http://somewhereelse.com/$1
```

Versus this, which will redirect to `http://somewhereelse.com/?page=wherever`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/redirect\.php([?]page=.+)?$ http://somewhereelse.com/$1
```

Does `RedirectMatch` only match the URI and not the query string? Apache's documentation is a bit vague in this area. What I'm *trying* to do is extract the `page` query parameter and redirect to another site using it.

Is that possible with `RedirectMatch` or do I have to use `RewriteCond` + `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible to use `RedirectMatch` in this case unfortunately; the query string is not part of URL string that `RewriteMatch` is compared to.

The second example works because the query string the client sent is re-appended to the destination URL - so the optional match is matching nothing, the `$1` replacement is an empty string, but then the client's original query string is stuck back on.

A `RewriteCond` check against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` will be needed instead.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/redirect\.php$ http://somewhereelse.com/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Something very similar to this is what I ended up using. Thanks!

Comment: For other readers who are using `.htaccess` (or in a _directory_ context), you'll need to remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, ie. `^redirect\.php$`. Because when used in `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is less the _directory-prefix_, it's not the full URL-path.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it matches against URL:

> The supplied regular expression is matched against the URL-path

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

> Every URL consists of the following: the scheme name (commonly called
>   protocol), followed by a colon, two slashes, then, depending
>   on scheme, a server name (exp. ftp., www., smtp., etc.) followed by a
>   dot (.) then a domain name (alternatively, IP address), a port
>   number, the path of the resource to be fetched or the program to be
>   run, then, for programs such as Common Gateway Interface (CGI)
>   scripts, a query string, and an optional fragment
>   identifier.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator  (section Syntax)

You can do that with RewriteRule

Comment: Thanks, but Apache's [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html) on nomenclature don't specify whether the URL-path includes the query string or not.

Comment: That's what PATH means. There are various parts to a URL, the path and the query-strings are two parts.